# SoapHeader class and DataContractAttribute

Tags: vb.net, wcf, soapheader

I have an error:

```
Type 'MyAppApp.Web.MyAppWebService.NotifierAuthHeader' cannot inherit from a type that is not marked with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute. Consider marking the base type 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader' with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute, or removing them from the derived type.
```

while executing this wcf method:

```
<OperationContract()> <WebMethod(Description:="Gets details about selected PDF document")> _
    Public Function GetPdfDetails(ByVal pdfName As String) As String
```

I couldn't change   `SoapHeader` because it's framework class

```
Public MustInherit Class SoapHeader
          Inherits System.Object
     Member of System.Web.Services.Protocols
```

and I use this class in      `NotifierAuthHeader` class

```
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization 

Public Class NotifierAuthHeader
    Inherits SoapHeader

    Public HandlerId As Integer
    Public Guid As Byte()
End Class
```

I'm confused a bit. How can I have that working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you deliberately trying to mix two technologies? `SoapHeader` is from the legacy ASMX technology, but `OperationContract` is from WCF.

To use headers in WCF, you need to use a Message Contract, which can contain header parts as well as body parts.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to separate the WebMethod from the OperationContract.

If the goal is to use the same method for a Web Service and a WCF service, then you will need to move a copy of the method into a separate asmx.